# Python check if string contains words from specific list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of string.

```
constants = ["{{first_name}}", "{{last_name}}", "{{order_num}}", {{order_date}}"]

order_string = " Hello, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}, Thanks for purchasing. You order number is {{order_num}} "
```

I have two inputs, constants and order_string above. I want to check if order_string contain any substring that start from '{' or '{{', like {{first_name}}, then this substring {{first_name}} must be in constant variable. If it's not in the list then order_string contain invalid substring.
For e.g.

```
order_string = "Hello, {first_name}} {{last_name}}, Thanks for purchasing. You order number is {{or_num}}."
```

Here above, you can see order_string variable contain substring {first_name}} and {{or_num}} which not exists in constants variable.

I have tried this

```
str_list = order_string.split()

for item in str_list:
    print(item)
    if re.search("({+|}+)", item):
        print('has format')
        if not item in constant:
            raise Exception()
```

It works for string like

```
order_string = "Hello, {{first_name}} last_name}} .Your order number is {{order_num}}".
```

But it fails that any substring contain dot, comman or any characters at the last. Like this

```
order_string = "Hello, {{first_name}} last_name}}. Your order number is {{order_num}}."
```

Comment: Please mention expected input and output. It is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I have update the question. Let me know if doubt still exists.

Comment: `order_string = " Hello, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}, Thanks for purchasing. You order number is {{order_num}} {{blah}} "

exprs =re.findall(r'(\{\{[^}]+\}\})', order_string)
print([e for e in exprs if e not in constants])`

Comment: @shahkalpeshp it will only filter out that has specific format. Like if order_string = "Hello, {{first_name}} last_name}}. Your order number is {{order_num}}", then exprs  = ['{{first_name}}', '{{order_num}}']. It didn't catch the "last_name}}" which I need as it is in wrong format.

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
order_string = " Hello, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}, Thanks for purchasing. You order number is {{order_num}} "

a = order_string.split()
a[2] = a[2].split(',')[0]

for i in a:
     if i in constants:
          print(i)
```